# Syntax to get PHP variables into jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php function:

```
<?php
function send_message($userid, $projectid, $message) {
    //some code
}

$userid = '1';
$projectid = '2';
$message = 'hello';
?>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
    <textarea name="message" id="project-message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send message">
</form>
```

I want the submit button to do jQuery Ajax so my page won't refresh:

js:

```
 $('#myform').on('submit',function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: //my valid url,
            type: 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: { 
                action: 'send_message', //this is the PHP function
                projectid: projectid //how do I write this?,
                userid: userid //how do I write this?,
                message: message//how do I write this?'
            },
        })

        .done(function(data) { console.dir(data);; })
        .fail(function(jqXHR) { alert('You are fail. ' + jqXHR); });

    });
```

On my error.log, I get NULL for the 3 parameters because I'm not sure how to access them from my PHP. How do you access the PHP variables from jQuery?

Comment: Where you have data:{ it should be something like this: success: function(data) {, and check if your url is right... and i don't thing that action is right there...

Comment: IF your jquery is on the same page as the PHP just echo them in the correct position, otherwise put them in hidden inputs

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your PHP variables into hidden inputs so they'll be automatically sent when it is submitted.
   For example : `<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">`
2. Serialize the form data : `var formData = $(form).serialize();`
3. On submit attach your form data :

`$.ajax({
    url: admin_ajax.ajax_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData
})`

4. Access it from PHP with a classic way : `$_POST['userid']`

Comment: but how about my action: 'send_projectmessage' ? That's my PHP function that needs the formData as parameters. How do I write them together in data: { }

Comment: var formData = $(form).serialize() + "&moredata=" + morevalue

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the values of the form, and submit it. 
Also you can set other the values in the form as hidden.

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="" id='form1'>
    <textarea name="projectMessage" id="project-message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send message">
    <?php print "<input type='hidden' value='$userid' > "; name='userid' ?>
    <?php print "<input type='hidden' value='$projectid' > "; name='projectid' ?>
    <?php print "<input type='hidden' value='$message' > "; name='message' ?>
</form>
```

```
$('#myform').on('submit',function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: admin_ajax.ajax_url,
            type: 'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data: $("#form1").serialize(),
        })

        .done(function(data) { console.dir(data);; })
        .fail(function(jqXHR) { alert('You are fail. ' + jqXHR); });

    });
```

I like this approach because I can reuse the ajax multiple times or even create a generic function to submit the form on the background with ajax. Also I can fill the form using a for each loop in php, having all the values in an array (like a database result)

ex.

```
<?php
foreach($values as $k=>$v}{
     print "<input name='$key' value='$v'>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="insert_form">
<textarea name="message" id="project-message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="send message">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo $userid= '1'; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="projectid" id="projectid" value="<?php echo $projectid='2'; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="message" id="message" value="<?php echo $message= 
'hello'; ?>">
</form>

var project-message=document.getElementById('project-message').value;
var send=document.getElementById('send').value;
var userid=document.getElementById('userid').value;
var projectid=document.getElementById('projectid').value;
var message=document.getElementById('message').value;
 $.ajax({
url:"your_url.php",
 type:"POST",
data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),
success:function(data)
{
}
})
```

Comment: A few words explaining your solution as well as some code formatting would do wonders here!